# Custom form elements script

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a customized Form elements like RadioButton, Checkbox and Selectbox
script.
What do you suggest. (widthout using any framework please!)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What aspects exactly do you want to customize?

Comment: How can it be a custom element without being part of the framework that includes it?

Comment: Why am I giving 2 negative points on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [jQuery checkbox/radio button plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/checkbox-radiobutton/), I think it does what you're looking for.